# Combining objects to rigged characters

Tags: modeling, animation

I want to combine a pair of sunglasses to a character that is rigged. Although rigged, there is no animation yet but when I move the character in pose mode, the sunglasses are not moving with the character even though they are joined. How can I fix this? I'm sure it is a simple fix, but I can't find it anywhere.

In general, I want to know how to combine clothes to a character so that they will move at the same time (not using cloth simulation or anything)

Answer (score 1):

If your glasses are part of the same object as the rest of the character, select the glasses mesh in *Edit* mode, go into the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups*, select the vertex group it should be part of (the one that has the name of the bone that is supposed to control it, let's say *head* for example), and click on the *Assign* button. Now the glasses mesh is part of the *head* vertex groups and therefore will be controlled by the *head* bone.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm fairly new to blender, when I select the glasses should I select each vertices in edit mode or is there another way?

Comment: it worked, I had to unbind the rig from the character first though but thank you so much

Comment: To select the whole glasses use L. As for the unbind I'm not sure what you mean, you should not need to unparent the character if this is what you mean

Comment: For some reason when I did your method, it would only move the rest except the part that was combined to the bone. I'm not sure what had happened, it was probably my past process that made it even more difficult. But now that I've figured it out I can relay this method later, thank you & I love your username haha

Comment: if you want you can share your file as it was at the begining so that we test  ;)  my username is stupid but now i'm trapped  ^^